# When is compaction triggered when using sstableloader?

Tags: cassandra

When is compaction triggered when using sstableloader? 
In some scenarios, loading a lot of SSTables that are not compacted properly could lead to a very large compaction which will effect cluster performance.

More specifically, when using [DateTiered](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/dtcs-notes-from-the-field) compaction what happens if:

1) The SSTables don't have a proper timestamp?

2) All the SSTabels are in the same time window?

3) We load 64 SSTables of size 'base_time_seconds', would it trigger 21 (16 + 4 + 1) complications?